# Setting up elasticsearch with Haystack

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I used to be using `Whoosh` as a search backend but now I'm switching to `elasticsearch` and trying to get things working.

When trying to rebuild the index I get the error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /_bulk?op_type=create (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 61] Connection refused)
```

The following is in my settings.py:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://localhost:8000/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

My question is, what is URL used for and what do I put here? I'm running things locally for development and I'm deployed on Heroku.

Comment: the default port for ES is 9200.  so unless you reconfigured it to 8000, just switch your port number.

Answer (score 4):

The port should be 9200.

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

Also, you have to be sure that you are using the development version (2.0) of haystack.

---

*Edit:*

You probably want to make sure first that ElasticSearch is running by executing the following command:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_mapping?pretty=1'
```

Comment: I followed your answer, yet am still getting the error above.

Comment: If you are getting exactly the same error `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000)`, then you placed the code in the wrong place (it should be in the `settings` of the project and depending which server you are using, you should restart it). If the error says `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port:9200)`, then either ElasticSearch is not running on your machine or, less probable, it is working on a different port.

Comment: You can test that ElasticSearch is running by executing the following command in the terminal: `curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_mapping?pretty=1'`

Comment: I'm getting curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Comment: But whenever I run sudo service elasticsearch start, it won't bring out any error. It will run fine. I don't know why I'm still getting that error since I can run elasticsearch.

Comment: It seems it is running in a different port. If you haven't edit the configuration of elastic search (`elasticsearch.yml`), there might be another server running on that port. Can you try the port 9201: `curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9201/my_index/_mapping?pretty=1'`? (based on [this](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/config/elasticsearch.yml#L194))

Comment: You can change the port in `elasticsearch.yml` with the parameter http.port: 9199 (or any you think is free, [see the file](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/config/elasticsearch.yml#L220)).  In ubuntu, you should be able to find it here `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`. Restart elasticsearch after changing the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks.. I actually did pip install pyelasticsearch==0.5 . Once again, thanks for the help. Happy New Year :)

Comment: Wow.. elasticsearch is hilarious.. Now, it's still giving me the same error after running update_index

Comment: Every variable are all commented in elasticsearch.yml, should I go on and change the port number on this line # http.port: 9200
?

Comment: Nope, it's not.. I changed it back to 9200 and I restarted elasticsearch server and run rebuild_index, and it worked. I was able to search, but after sometime, when I search with the keywords I used earlier, nothing seems to come up. Even the objects I have in my db, when I search for them with their name, nothing came up. Could this be that elasticsearch is timing out by itself?

Comment: You might want to try [elasticsearch-head] (https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head). It is a web frontend for elastic search or [elasticsearch-browser](https://github.com/OlegKunitsyn/elasticsearch-browser/). I never tried them though.